# Precisely speaking, how can we understand Taylor series in the prespective of Lie Algebras?

Tags: taylor-expansion, lie-groups, lie-algebras

It seems to me, that many of the critical ideas in Lie Theory has a feeling of Taylor series behind it. For example, we have the concept of linearizing a continous group to get a lie algebra, and then getting back the group by exponentiation. The way the linearlizing seems quite similar to how we linearly approximate functions:

$$ f(a+h) \approx  \left[ (1+h \frac{d}{dx})  f(x) \right]_{x=a}$$

And, how we get back the total taylor series seem somewhat similar to how we have to exponentiate the group element (here we do $h \frac{d}{dx}$. Coincidence, or something deeper?

---

## What I got so far:

$\mathbb{R^d}$ is in general a lie group, we even in higher dimension, we have this similar ideas to the said above applicable.

> [image]

Comment: What is your question? Let's consider a smooth complex manifold. Then smooth means analytical means Taylor. Lie algebras are the tangent spaces. Tangent means linear approximation, means the second term of Taylor. The representation of functions by Taylor series are naturally involved here. Your formula is a flow through a vector field. Here is an article about the historic development: https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/when-lie-groups-became-physics/

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by what is your question? Not clear to me since I wrote it on the usbject

Comment: Funny enough, I've been reading the actual book that article more or less copies from, so it didn't tell me anything new @MariusS.L.

Comment: The answer is "something deeper" then, which I tried to explain. The consideration of functions as represented by series is actually the historic approach.

Comment: I think etwas fehlt @MariusS.L.

Comment: The short version of the Taylor series is $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\mathcal{O}(x^2).$ Weierstraß's formula for a derivative is $f(x)=f(x-v) +  f'(x)\cdot v + o(v).$ They both deal with a linear approximation of a curved manifold. Of course, they are related.